# Palantir-Foundry - Use 'context' in a python transform fails

Tags: pyspark, ontology, palantir-foundry, foundry-code-repositories

I would like to compare data coming from a fusion sheet with data integrated in an object type; while users are able to update and create data in Object Explorer, I need to compare with the writeback dataset's data.

The writeback dataset can't be an input in a transform where the output is the related backing dataset: it raises a circular dependency error.
So I tried to read the writeback dataset from the context, using something like this:

```py
@transform(
    my_fusion=Input("fusion_dataset_path"),
    my_output=Output("backing_dataset_path")
)
def my_compute_function(my_input, my_output, ctx):
    my_writeback = ctx._foundry.input("write_back_dataset_path", branch="master")
    my_df = ... # All controls come here
    my_output.write_dataframe(my_df)
```

The problem is that it's not accepted because of an error:

> ValueError: Could not find resource with path *write_back_dataset_path*

I do not understand why it fails in this case, while I already used this kind of syntax for other transforms.
Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Try providing a full Foundry dataset RID in place of `write_back_dataset_path`, e.g. `ri.foundry.main.dataset.abcd1234-de56-fg78-hi90-jklmno123456`

Comment: I already tried and it doesn't change anything. Worse, I encountered situations where I absolutely needed to use the dataset's full path

Comment: Could this be due to that the foundry-token that is being used is project scoped?

Comment: @nicornk sorry but I don't know what you're talking about, could you please explain? I ensured the dataset I intend to read like this actually already **are** in the project scope, I also tried to create a dummy transform to ensure it as relevant set up (transforms-shrinkwrap.yml), bunt it wasn't successful

Comment: To me it looks like Palantir is artificially (argument: "we want to have the full lineage captured") restricting the ability to access any dataset that is not mentioned in your transform decorator. I reproduced your issue on my stack and I also get the "Could not find resource with path" error, even though the datasets are in the same project.

Comment: On top of that, a writeback dataset does actually not belong to the repository, si it's not allowed to read data using the context. Of course, duplicate this dataset will not work because the copy would be declared as an output of 2 different transforms the first one to be built, the second one to be declared in the context, event if it's not actually updated)... at the end of the day, I do not see how to manage this

Comment: hey Christophe, I've been looking for some days at this question but don't have an answer, it looks like you are using a non documented private api. As @nicornk says this looks like a generic error probably due to lineage and shrinkwrap constrains. Generating Inputs at run time is not something recommended or usually possible within foundry

Comment: thanks fmsf for taking care of my issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After several searches and attempts, I went to the conclusion that this is just NOT possible.

There are 2 ways to involve a dataset in a transform: either declare it as input or output, or open it as part of the context. Neither option is allowed:

- A writeback dataset cannot be used as an input if it's related backing dataset is the output, it raises a circular dependency error. And this is checked at repository level, which means you can't use intermediate datasets. In this case, setting it as an output does not make sens
- A writeback dataset is not part of a repository context, because the repository is not the owner: a writeback is managed by Ontology process, Ontology is 'responsible' for building it.

I finally found a workaround for my problem: the validation process is run twice: a first time it leads to a 'technical' dataset that the user do not see, where all updates are applied. Then a second time to build the output dataset, that the user sees. He applies changes on it and they are replicated on the first one, to allow this second validation process to run again and validated the edited data. All of this is based on action types and Workshop for the user interface.